# How to access a dynamically created element

Tags: automated-testing, c#, javascript, watin

> I am using Watin to test a website. It contains a div which is created dynamically on clicking a tablecell. How can I access the dynamically created div. The issue is the div is deleted after a short span of time (even before the control can move to next line)

```
 if(tablecell.exists)
{
tablecell.ClickNoWait(); //this creates the dynamic <div>
if(div.exists) //the control does not go inside 
{
//code to edit div contents.
}
}
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the HTML/JavaScript referencing the div? The way you access it will depend on how the div is coded.

Comment: <div class="somevalue" style="somevalue">
 <input type="text" value="" name="somevalue" id="processing">
</div>
the <div> element is created after clicking a tablecell and is destroyed immediately if we click or do anything anywhere else.

Comment: Can you please edit the question, as well as giving the HTML around the div and the javascript that "creates" the div element? There's a difference between the div contents being generated dynamically in response to an event through javascript and the contents being made visible in response to an event.

Comment: Thank you for reply, but the problem has been solved.

Comment: In that case, could you answer your question with the solution you found and mark it as answered? That will help others who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used threading. I put the main thread to sleep.
and then started the child thread which was responsible for handling the textbox

```
current_frame.Div(Find.ById(id)).Table(Find.ById(id)).TableCell(Find.ByClass(id)).TableCell(Find.ByClass(id)).ClickNoWait();
                  Thread.Sleep(0);
                  child_thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                  child_thread.Start();
                  child_thread.Join();
```

child_thread contains code for editing the textbox.